# Laravel ACL, Roles adm by Permissions

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have this plugins [Laravel ACL](https://github.com/kodeine/laravel-acl/wiki/Installation). It es very good but I need to do anything but I don't know if it is possible.

I made a permission like is in the doc:

```
$permission = new Permission();
$permUser = $permission->create([ 
    'name'        => 'user',
    'slug'        => [          // pass an array of permissions.
        'create'     => true,
        'view'       => true,
        'update'     => true,
        'delete'     => true,
        'view.phone' => true
    ],
    'description' => 'manage user permissions'
]);
```

And after I assign it to a Role:

```
$roleAdmin = Role::first(); 
$roleAdmin->assignPermission($permUser);
```

And it works amazing.

BUT what happens if I want the same Permission but with "user.delete" in false or after in true? depends what the admin want?

I'm trying to make a "crud" of Roles and the administrator can update this "slug".

So, how I can update this "slug" if depends of admin?

I see the [inheritance](https://github.com/kodeine/laravel-acl/wiki/Permissions-Inheritance) but I need to make a permission for create, delete, update, view or anything for every "slug's permission". It is neccesary always? or can avoid it?

Or anyone has other plugin seems to it?

Thanks everyone

Comment: For example: Super Admin Role -> all true / Admin Role -> create, edit, view true and delete false.

But Super Admin can edit Admin Role and put it all true when he wants